# Does PeekMessage never generate new WM_TIMER messages if there's something in the queue already, regardless of filters?

Tags: winapi, timer, message

I understand `WM_TIMER` messages are generated on the fly by `Get` & `Peek`, based on some flag that says "a timer has elapsed, when you're ready post a timer message".

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-timer):

> The WM_TIMER message is a low-priority message. The GetMessage and
>   PeekMessage functions post this message only when no other
>   higher-priority messages are in the thread's message queue.

Does this mean that `PeekMessage` will return `False` (i.e no messages) if I use it with a filter like:

```
messageFound = PeekMessage(&msg, hwnd, WM_TIMER, WM_TIMER, PM_REMOVE)
```

if there are *any* messages of higher priority in the queue; **even ones that don't match the filter**? So both of these queues would return false because of the presence of a (non-matching) high priority message

```
WM_NOTIFY                        or        WM_NOTIFY
--Flag to autogenerate timer--             WM_TIMER
```

Will `WM_SYS­TIMER` have an impact because it's in the [same group](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=93745) as `WM_TIMER`

Or does it simply mean that if I have no filter then no new auto-generated `WM_TIMER` messages will be *created* if other messages are in the queue, but any that are *already there* (from say a Peek + PM_NOREMOVE) will behave like normal messages? (i.e. Peek now just returns whichever was posted first)

---

```
If highPriorityMessagesExist() Then
    Return anyOfThemMatchTheFilter()
Else 
    If !lowPriorityMessagesExist()
        tryGenerateSomeFromFlags()

    If lowPriorityMessagesExist()
        Return anyOfThemMatchTheFilter()
    Else
        Return False
```

vs

```
If anyMessagesMatchTheFilter()
    Return True
Else
    tryGenerateSomeFromFlags()
Return anyMessagesMatchTheFilter()
```

Comment: Raymond Chen touches on this subject in his [Why is my message queue full of WM_TIMER messages?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160624-00/?p=93745) blog article.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I've read a lot of Raymond Chen's articles on timer messages, but they haven't helped sort out this particular confusion

Comment: "*If a request for a message is about to say, “Nope, no matching messages,” the window manager makes one last check: “Is there an auto-generated message that could satisfy this request?” If so, then it generates the message, and hey look, there’s a message!*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WM_TIMER message generation will not happen if there are messages in the filter range that are high priority. However if there are high priority messages in the queue but they are filtered out by the wMsgFilterMin and wMsgFilterMax parameters of GetMessage or PeekMessage, WM_TIMER messages will still be generated.

In other words this program *will* generate debug output:

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    SetTimer(NULL, 101, 500, NULL);

    auto start = GetTickCount();
    while (GetTickCount() - start < 4000) {
        MSG msg;
        PostMessage(NULL, WM_NOTIFY, 0, 0);
        GetMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_TIMER, WM_TIMER);
        if (msg.message == WM_TIMER)
            OutputDebugStringA("WM_TIMER\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but the following program will not generate debug output, because WM_NOTIFY is now in the filter range:

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    SetTimer(NULL, 101, 500, NULL);

    auto start = GetTickCount();
    while (GetTickCount() - start < 4000) {
        MSG msg;
        PostMessage(NULL, WM_NOTIFY, 0, 0);
        GetMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_NOTIFY, WM_TIMER);
        if (msg.message == WM_TIMER)
            OutputDebugStringA("WM_TIMER\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very clear. Just one point though: What if in your second example you manually post a WM_TIMER *then* WM_NOTIFY - is there a mechanism still to ignore the timer message as it is "low priority", or once created does it act like any other message? (i.e. there would be debug output)

Comment: If you manually post a WM_TIMER message it behaves like any other kind of message in the queue. The special behavior only has to do with the automatic generation of WM_TIMER messages that happen because SetTimer was called.